# Phonegap plugin twitter: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter

Tags: twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I am using [Phonegap Twitter](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms) + childbrowser. It is working well on android but is giving me issues on iOS.

I am receiving issue for "Invalid oauth_verifier parameter" by using this [oauth library](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth/downloads) and facing this issue when calling

```
oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_verifier='+verifier+'&'+requestParams,
```

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot comment on the specific library you talk about, I can recommend the jso oauth library which I've successfully used for an iOS app: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso

Good luck!